# Problema al no tener una imagen en Storage de Firebase

Tags: java, android, glide

Tengo una app donde empresas se pueden registrar y tienen la opción se subir una imagen de su empresa para mostrar en el perfil, el problema es que si ellos no suben la imagen al Storage, cuando realizo una acción en la Activity me salta el siguiente error...

```
W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [-1x-1]
         class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model
```

Este error ocurre porque todavía no han subido ninguna imagen a su perfil

Y este es el código que me genera el error...

```
if (item.child("Logo").exists()) {
                                Logo = item.child("Logo").getValue().toString();
                            }

                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                    .load(Logo)
                                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                            .placeholder(R.drawable.negociophoto)
                                            .centerCrop()
                                            .dontAnimate()
                                            .dontTransform())
                                    .into(logoempresa);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Una pregunta @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas , Logo tiene una url o es un recurso dentro del proyecto? Generalmente se usa una url

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, así es, Logo tiene una URL distinta dependiendo del usuario que sube la imagen

Comment: Excelente, bueno el problema es debido a que no se aceptan valores nulos, de hecho similar a Glide , Picasso también debe validarse @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas saludos.

Comment: se cierra la app o que pasa en este caso?

Comment: @armen me cierra la Activity o Fragment en el que me encuentro y me devuelve al Activity o Fragment principal o de inicio...

Comment: y ya probaste con .error(). Yo he probado en fragments y adapters y no se cierra la app

Comment: @armen Y cómo es tu código? Lo que pasa es que en la Database no tengo ningún dato guardado, por eso me arroja error...

Comment: Glide "acepta" valores null pero con el método .error(), para en caso de que el servidor este caído o no exista la imagen. Es como un if/else si encuentra la imagen la carga, si no, carga la que esta en .error(imagen en Drawable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas un if/else, solo una línea de código (`.error()`), ya sea en el Adapter o Fragment/Activity:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
.load(Logo)
.apply(new RequestOptions()
.placeholder(R.drawable.negociophoto)
.centerCrop()
.dontAnimate()
.dontTransform())
.error(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tu_imagen))
.into(logoempresa);
```

Con esto si `Glide` encuentra el valor, carga la imagen, de lo contrario cargaría una imagen que selecciones de `drawable`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `Glide` trata de cargar un recurso que no existe.

> class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null
>   model class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to
>   load resource

En este caso como una opción puedes validar antes de realizar la carga de la imagen (variable `Logo`)

```
if(Logo != null || && !Logo.trim().equals("")){
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                    .load(Logo)
                                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                            .placeholder(R.drawable.negociophoto)
                                            .centerCrop()
                                            .dontAnimate()
                                            .dontTransform())
                                    .into(logoempresa);
    }
```

---

Otra opción: Puedes mostrar una imagen en caso de que el recurso a cargar no existe o el valor de este sea `null`, puedes usar el método `error()`.

> [error()](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.html#error-int-) : Establece un recurso para mostrar si falla una carga.

Ejemplo cargando la imagen `R.drawable.negociophoto` en caso de ocurrir un error en la carga:

```
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                    .load(Logo)
                                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                            .placeholder(R.drawable.negociophoto)
                                            .centerCrop()
                                            .dontAnimate()
                                            .dontTransform()
                                         .error(R.drawable.negociophoto)) 
                                    .into(logoempresa);
```

---

**Importante** comentar que en la [versión 4 de Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html) no importa si la variable que contiene el recurso a carga tiene valor `null` o no existe, no se generara un error.

Comment: Y en caso de que no cumpla con ninguno de esos if, cómo podría mostrar un drawable sin tener que implementar la parte .load(Logo)

Comment: Creo que tendría que hacerlo a través de xml nomás

Comment: actualizo @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas

Comment: Será buena opción guardar una imagen en el Storage que sea como el drawable negociophoto para que esta se cargue desde la database en caso de que el Logo sea null y así no me de el error?

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas Si la vas a descargar en  "storage" esto implica que la tienes que descargar, en este caso la cargarías por ejemplo: .load(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/imagen_dummy.png")) pero lo común y normal me parece que sería agregar la imagen dentro de tu directorio /drawable para que no implique descargarla ya que tendrías que agregar lógica en el caso de que hacer si no se pudo descargar la imagen por alguna razón..

Comment: entonces Glide no acepta valores null a pesar de contar con .error();?

Comment: @armen Si acepta valores nulos, al menos estoy seguro en la versión 4, si lo que trata de cargar no existe entonces carga lo definido en .error(..........)