# Cargar imágenes desde un formulario a un ImageView con Glide

Tags: java, android, glide

Estoy cargando imágenes desde un formulario a un RecyclerView. Tengo creado de tal forma que si le doy al botón "+" me deja colocar me deja colocar una imagen de galería y o tomada desde la cámara.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero además de esto, para el Spinner, le tengo asignado que cada elemento de la lista le asigne una imagen por defecto que la he cargado a través de Glide:

```
spTypePets.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Resources res = getResources();
        String spinner = spTypePets.getSelectedItem().toString();

        switch (position) {

            case 0:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.dog).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 1:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.cat).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 2:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.mouse).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 3:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.fish).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 4:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.birds).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 5:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.reptile).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 6:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.other).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

        }

    }
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que ahora necesito cargar también esa imagen por defecto al crear un objeto del tipo "Pet" a través de dicho formulario, es decir: si no hace ninguna foto, que salga la foto por defecto y pueda cargarla.

```
 btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            realm.beginTransaction();

            Pets pet = new Pets();

            pet.setPetName(etPetName.getText().toString());
            pet.setPetType(petTypeLst.get(spTypePets.getSelectedItemPosition()));
            pet.setPetUrlImage(imagePath);

            Number maxId = realm.where(Pets.class).max("id");
            long nextID;

            if (maxId == null) {
                nextID = 1;
            } else {
                nextID = maxId.longValue() + 1;
            }

            pet.setId(nextID);

            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(pet);
            realm.commitTransaction();

            finish();

        }
    });
```

Se que además de en Glide como la estoy guardando, también debo guardarla en "Pet" para que se añada, pero no tengo ni idea como. A ver si me podéis echar una mano. Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: porqué no revisar si el campo imagen está nulo, para asignarla por defecto aunque no se guarde la imagen en tu objeto?

Comment: con Glide usa una imagen placeholder, además una de "error", este en caso de que obtenga null (por ejemplo cuando no haya conexion) que deben estar en drawable. Checa mi respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191136/problema-al-no-tener-una-imagen-en-storage-de-firebase/191156#191156

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer, es saber si `imagePath` tiene un valor, si no lo tiene, asignar el valor que obtiene del spinner, podemos hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Antes de empezar, necesitamos saber que drawable necesitas, basados en el spinner. en una de tus clases, ya tienes un bloque de código que define un drawable en base a lo que tiene el spinner, vamos a aprovecharlo. En la clase donde tienes el switch, crea un String  (no dentro de ningún método, para que sea accesible para toda la clase):

```
public String imagenSeleccionada="";
```

Teniendo ese string, aprovechemos tu switch:

```
    switch (position) {

                case 0:

                    Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.dog).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                    imagenSeleccionada="drawable://" + R.drawable.dog;
                    break;

                case 1:

                    Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.cat).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                    imagenSeleccionada="drawable://" + R.drawable.cat;
                    break;

                case 2:

                    Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.mouse).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                    imagenSeleccionada="drawable://" + R.drawable.mouse;
                    break;

                case 3:

                    Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.fish).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                    imagenSeleccionada="drawable://" + R.drawable.fish;
                    break;

                case 4:

                    Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.birds).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                    imagenSeleccionada="drawable://" + R.drawable.birds;
                    break;

                case 5:

                    Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.reptile).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                    imagenSeleccionada="drawable://" + R.drawable.reptile;
                    break;

                case 6:

                    Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.other).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                    imagenSeleccionada="drawable://" + R.drawable.other;
                    break;

            }
```

lo que hicimos en el bloque de código anterior, es guardar en la varbiable `imagenSeleccioanda`, el `drawable` por defecto que carga del `spinner`. Entonces, ahora ya sabemos qué agregar a tu campo `pet.setUriImage`

```
if(imagePath.Length>0){ 
      //imagepath tiene algo, procedemos a guardarlo como lo tenías en el código
      pet.setPetUrlImage(imagePath);
}else{ 
     //imagepath no tiene nada, necesitamos obtener un drawable basados en el valor del spinner.
     //imagenSeleccioanda tiene el valor del drawable seleccionado del spinner, usémoslo
     pet.setPetUrlImage(imagenSeleccionada);
}
```

Por lo que me comentaste, si imagePath no tiene nada, lo guarda como vacío, entonces, validé que, el valor de `imagePath` sea diferente de vacio `""`, obteniendo la longitud de ese campo. Si la longitud es 0, significa que no tiene nada, y entoces el if entra en acción.

Espero mi respuesta te sirva, saludos *android máster* :D

Comment: Como comenté ayer, al ejecutar esto me da un Null Pointer, voy a intentar ver por mi cuenta porque puede ser, pero si alguien más echa una mano se agradece